# Is there a way to "deserialze" a field paths in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm working on a generic dao bean similar to [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html). The principal difference is that this tool will streamline fetching, filtering and sorting. I have it working almost perfectly. One problem which I am still facing is that I need the jpa path. I would like to be able to pass in the path as it is rendered by Jackson (accounting for `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonUnwrapped`. To that end I am in need of the ability to effectively serialize a path. I know that I can do this myself, but I am reluctant to devote the blood sweat and tears unless I am sure that such a thing already exists.

Is there a way to get the jpa path to a field using the path resulting from jackson serialization?
**EXAMPLE**

```
class A {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    B b;
    @JsonProperty("c_property")
    C c;
}
class C {
    String field;
}
class B {
    String field;
}
```

is there a `method` such that

```
method(A.class, "field")->"b.field"
method(A.class, "c_property.field")->"c.field"
```

Comment: soooo...........